# Issue with node positions after updating d3 to v4

Tags: d3.js

I want to update the "Modifying a Force Layout" example to d3 v4. The working example is https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795

When I do though, the nodes appear in the top left corner. How do I correct this?
You can view my fork at https://bl.ocks.org/stevescc/f964f8f4658bc11319765f83f67b7f9f

To see the changes I made in my fork see [here](https://gist.github.com/stevescc/f964f8f4658bc11319765f83f67b7f9f/revisions). As far as I'm aware, the only changes I've made are those caused by the change to v4.

Below is the full index.html for completeness.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.link {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node {
  fill: #000;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node.a { fill: #1f77b4; }
.node.b { fill: #ff7f0e; }
.node.c { fill: #2ca02c; }

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var nodes = [],
    links = [];

var force = d3.forceSimulation()    
    .nodes(nodes)
    .force("link", d3.forceLink(links)
        .distance(120))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-400))
    .force("X", d3.forceX().x(width/2))
    .force("Y", d3.forceY().y(height/2))
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var node = svg.selectAll(".node"),
    link = svg.selectAll(".link");

// 1. Add three nodes and three links.
setTimeout(function() {
  var a = {id: "a"}, b = {id: "b"}, c = {id: "c"};
  nodes.push(a, b, c);
  links.push({source: a, target: b}, {source: a, target: c}, {source: b, target: c});
  start();
}, 0);

// 2. Remove node B and associated links.
setTimeout(function() {
  nodes.splice(1, 1); // remove b
  links.shift(); // remove a-b
  links.pop(); // remove b-c
  start();
}, 3000);

// Add node B back.
setTimeout(function() {
  var a = nodes[0], b = {id: "b"}, c = nodes[1];
  nodes.push(b);
  links.push({source: a, target: b}, {source: b, target: c});
  start();
}, 6000);

function start() {
  link = link.data(force.force('link').links(), function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });
  link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");
  link.exit().remove();

  node = node.data(force.nodes(), function(d) { return d.id;});
  node.enter().append("circle").attr("class", function(d) { return "node " + d.id; }).attr("r", 8);
  node.exit().remove();

  force.restart();
}

function tick() {
  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })

  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
}

</script>
```

Comment: This definitely does not answer your question, but I've noticed that in your version the nodes are getting duplicated: while the original version starts with 3 nodes, then goes down to 2 and back to 3, your project starts with 3, which then raises to 5 and to 8. I guess that's not intentional, and probably is a sign of that there's something more basic going wrong.

Comment: To your question: if I get it right, in [v3](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Force-Layout.md#size) the center defaults to [width/2, height/2], while in [v4](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#forceCenter) it defaults to [0, 0]. I'd try adding something like `.force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));`, but as I mentioned in my earlier comment, probably other things have to be corrected first.

Comment: That's right @elias, when each timeout function is called it doesn't remove the previous nodes (ie exit().remove() isn't working) so the nodes are duplicated. I've also tried your suggestion of force centering x and y, which seems logical but still no luck.

Comment: Hi @Steve, one year later and I'm having exactly the same issue. Did you ever pinpoint what caused this?

Comment: @EmilyColeman , I noticed the author [updated](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795) the original to d3 v4. I see it needed to `merge` the entered elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block is updated (https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795) to d3 v4.
And the issue was the entered elements needed to be merged (`merge` function) with the existing elements.

Answer (score 0):

I would first add a centering force or better x and y forces as d3.centeringForce modifies positions rather than velocities and then add nodes in or near the center.

Here's an example:
https://bl.ocks.org/tezzutezzu/cd04b3f1efee4186ff42aae66c87d1a7

I have also changed how nodes are created / removed for clarity and added an accessor to select added/removed nodes.

update:
In the linked example entering nodes' position are the same as the first node. You can achieve the same result by modifying the function in my code in this way:

```js
function createNode(id) {
 var pos = nodes.length > 1 ? {x: nodes[0].x, y: nodes[0].y} : {x:width/2,y:height/2};
 return {id: id, x: pos.x, y:pos.y}
}
```

Comment: Centering force and X & Y forces added - still no luck. The example you link to Danilo is close to the other example but it initializes each node with a fixed position which is not what I want to do.

Comment: The example you provide shifts a lot of calls around and I'm trying to understand it. Do you know why simulation.node(nodes) is called every time in the start function and not when simulation is defined? Also, there is no force applied to node b when it is re-added, do you know why that is? Thanks

Comment: Hey Steven, I call simlulation.nodes as my node changes over time. As specified in the documentation: "If the specified array of nodes is modified, such as when nodes are added to or removed from the simulation, this method must be called again with the new (or changed) array to notify the simulation and bound forces of the change; the simulation does not make a defensive copy of the specified array."

Comment: Regarding node B: it has a force. In fact it has several: the one that repels it from the others, the ones from the links and the "centering" ones.

Comment: Still trying to understand all the differences. I've tried moving the variables outside the start and tick methods (eg var linkElements = svg.selectAll(".link")) so that it doesn't have to find the nodes on every start() and every tick(), but moving them outside doesn't work whereas in the example in v3 it does. I've also noticed that if I replace `simulation.restart()` with `simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()` it I observe an animation when node "b" is re-added.

Comment: bear in mind selections have changed between v3 and v4 (see docs)